# How to check the what is the field type of a field in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model. like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :username :campaign_id
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :username
end
```

if i fetch one user record like

```
u = User.first
```

it will return

```
#<User id: 190, name: "sa", :email: "abc@gmail.com", username: "ab">
```

So the question is: Is there any way to check whether one attribute e.g. 'name' is a **attr_accessor** or **attr_accessible?**

Comment: If not for adding tests/rspec, could you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually. i have some existing code overwritten by device. and raw password is also saved in db. but for device password is a attribute_accessor field so in my view i am not able to display the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the devise `attr_accessor :password` hides your password field in the database. To circumvent this, you could do something like

```
def raw_password
  self[:password]
end

def raw_password= (new_password)
  self[:password] = new_password
end
```

Of course, this is completely disregarding the fact that is not very safe to store the password in cleartext in the database. Devise offers enough mechanisms for users to manage their own password, so you should not be keeping the raw password for much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best solution, but by looking at [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb#L174) I guess you could check if `:name` appears in the `_accessible_attributes` field of your class or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether any object method is attr_accessor by:

```
my_object.respond_to?(:name) && my_object.respond_to?(:name=)
```

A return value of true indicates that both a getter and setter exist for :name.  This is just standard Ruby code and the very definition of the attr_accessor method:

> Defines a named attribute for this module, where the name is symbol.id2name, creating an instance variable (@name) and a corresponding access method to read it. Also creates a method called name= to set the attribute.

You can check if a method is attr_accessible by:

```
MyObject.attr_accessible[:default].deny?(:name)
```

where MyObject is the class name of your model and :name is the attribute you are querying. A return value of false means that the attribute is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to know if the attribute is just an instance variable created via `attr_accessor` or an actual column in database. You can get a list of db columns for a model via `User.column_names`. So a class method like below can work

```
# User.rb

def self.column_in_db?(attrib)
   column_names.include?(attrib.to_s)
end
```

Comment: Actually. i have some existing code overwritten by device. and raw password is also saved in db. but for device password is a attribute_accessor field so in my view i am not able to display the password.

Comment: So the attribute password is a db column and devise has it as attr_accessor. You would like to know how to display the password stored in db in a view?